# CharSequence и конвертация строк при выводе в консоль

Tags: java

Я новичок в Java и решал одну задачу по реализации интерфейсов. Вот во время решения одной из задач возник вопрос.

Каким образом происходит конвертация последовательности байтов в строку при вызове метода `System.out.println`?

В конструкторе мы не конверитируем байты в строку. Так каким образом вызов метода `System.out.println(answer)` выводит в консоль строку `Hello!`, а не массив байтов `{72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 33}`?

Я так понимаю, что где-то неявно вызывается метод `toString`.

```
class AsciiCharSequence implements CharSequence {
    final private byte[] bytes;

    AsciiCharSequence(byte[] bytes) {
        this.bytes = bytes.clone();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return new String(bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
        return bytes.length;
    }

    @Override
    public char charAt(int i) {
        return (char) bytes[i];
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        byte[] temp = new byte[end - start];
        for (int i = start, j = 0; i < end; i++) {
            temp[j++] = bytes[i];
        }
        System.out.println(temp);
        return new AsciiCharSequence(temp);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] example = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 33};
        AsciiCharSequence answer = new AsciiCharSequence(example);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Так и есть, когда применяешь метод `print` / `println` к объекту, то будет вызываться его метод `toString()`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, в методе `println` объект конвертируется в строку:

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```